# Display Google Sheets Table with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am looking to display the contents of my Google Sheet in the Logger. I am able to execute with no errors but the return value is 1 and not the complete 15x11 table I desire. Here is what I have:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AbIHSCGkBzzchLBTsUeNwhQ1WhiiC0THCzo2Br3Mc0U"),
  activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
  refDatasrc = ss.getSheetByName("Student"),
  refDataRange = ss.getDataRange(),
  values = refDataRange.getValues();
Logger.log("This how many records there are in the reference data sheet: " + values.length);
}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the values array to the Logger.

```
function test() {
  Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getValues());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your prompt reply I have found a similar solution by realizing that I wasn't specifying which sheet I wanted in the workbook so it reference the index. Here is what I changed:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1AbIHSCGkBzzchLBTsUeNwhQ1WhiiC0THCzo2Br3Mc0U"),
      activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet(),
      refDatasrc = ss.getSheetByName("Student"),
      refDataRange = ss.getDataRange(),
      values = refDataRange.getValues();
    Logger.log("This how many records there are in the reference data sheet: " + values.length)
  }
```